# Relationship using Visualforce and StandardController

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, relationships, standardcontroller

Is there a way to get related records using something like `{!Account.Contacts}` in a VF page with Custom Objects? Does the type of relationship matter? If I have a custom object and it has a look up relationship with another custom object, will something like `{!Custom_Object1__c.Custom_Object2__c}` work? Do I have to write an extension to query the appropriate records?

Answer (score 1):

With standard controllers, you can access one level of child relationships. See **[Accessing Data with a Standard Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_access_data.htm)**:

> You can traverse one level of parent-to-child relationships. For example, if using the Account standard controller, you can use {!account.Contacts} to return an array of all contacts associated with the account that is currently in context.

As for custom objects with a look-up relationship, you will be able to access them as well, but you need to use the child relationship name:

```
{!Custom_Object1__c.Custom_Object2s__r}
```

Note the **__r** suffix, and the child relationship name is the pluralized form of the object name since that is how it was defined when creating the look-up field (if you are unsure of the relationship name between your two objects, check the lookup field definition).

Comment: Thank you! There were two issues in the code I had:One, I only had a single underscore for the relationship. Two, I noticed that on the relationship field itself there is a definition for the 'Child Relationship Name'. In this case, it was not pluralized. Once I removed the 's', it worked. This is great because now I can use the standard set controller functionality.

Comment: @VanAlfredo excellent. I'm glad I could help!